# how can i generate random string with requirements in python?

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate random unique code with requirements :

1. At least one number
2. At least one string
3. It should 8 characters
4. No repeating strings and numbers in one line

here's my code

```
import random

chars = 'CDHKPQRVXY'
nums =  '123456789'
total = 10
rndstr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
rndint = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
random.choice(rndstr)
random.choice(rndint)

for i in range(total):
    selects = random.sample(chars, random.choice(rndstr)) + random.sample(nums, random.choice(rndint))
    random.shuffle(selects)
    unique_code = ''.join(selects)
    print(unique_code)
```

Expected Output :

```
1DXVQP7H
V3H6QP2K
R3562197
CDVQXHK9
```

The problem with the code above is that it doesn't meet the third point

Comment: Generate a random number `x` between 1 and 8; that's the amount of numbers you'll draw from `nums`. Then 8-`x` is the amount of random strings you draw from `chars`. For both you make a copy of both lists, and remove that item once you've drawn it. That way you'll have 8 characters, at least one string, at least one number, and no repeating characters/numbers.

Comment: thank you Sanderjuth, it's work, but i like the way of Guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep `random.choice(rndstr)` as a variable and decrease it from 8 when selecting random number

```
for i in range(total):
    str_len = random.choice(rndstr)
    selects = random.sample(chars, str_len) + random.sample(nums, 8 - str_len)
    random.shuffle(selects)
    unique_code = ''.join(selects)
    print(unique_code)
```

Comment: thank's Guy, it's work, but how if requirements changes at least 2 numbers and at least 2 strings in a one line?

Comment: @here you can remove 1 and 7 from the `rndstr` list, you can use slice of it `random.choice(rndstr[1:6])` and you can replace `rndstr` with `range` `random.choice(range(2, 7))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `randint` to chose the number of digits, no need for list to choose from:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as upp, digits as dig
from random import sample, shuffle, randint

for i in range(5):
    shuffle(s := sample(dig, n := randint(1, 7)) + sample(upp, 8-n))
    print("".join(s))

CYBOLN1K
3751NLIQ
05816R34
4012OC3E
GHWZB5SC
```

Comment: Okay thank you @schwobaseggl it works simple and fast, but i don't use all component in digits, but okay